# Loop through XML Nodes using XmlStringStreamer in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file which is something like this:
(fileName : abc.xml)

```
<Envelope>
    <Body>
        <SResponse>
            <Body>
                <SResponseDetails>
                    <SItem>...</SItem>
                    <SItem>...</SItem>
                    <SItem>...</SItem>
                    <SItem>...</SItem>
                </SResponseDetails>
            </Body>
        </SResponse>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I want to store all `<SItem>` in a db table (1 record for each SItem). I am using PHP for it and using XmlStringStreamer.

Here is my code for reading this file and processing it.

```
$streamer = \Prewk\XmlStringStreamer::createStringWalkerParser(__DIR__ . "/tempFile.xml");
$stream = new Stream\File(__DIR__ . "/abc.xml", 1024);
$parser = new Parser\StringWalker();
$streamer = new XmlStringStreamer($parser, $stream);
while ($node = $streamer->getNode()) {
    $simpleXmlNode = simplexml_load_string($node);
    //-- code here for getting single node
}
```

I am using XmlStringStreamer and did not get any answer from any forum, I also tried but could not get what I want so, can anyone please help me.

Thanks Alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it, here is my answer for it.
For looping for specific item, we can directly use this in xmlStringSteamer:

```
$stream = new Stream\File(__DIR__ . "/abc.xml", 1024);
$options = array(
    "uniqueNode" => "SItem"
);
$parser = new Parser\UniqueNode($options);

// Create the streamer
$streamer = new XmlStringStreamer($parser, $stream);

$countNodes = 0;
while ($node = $streamer->getNode())
{
    print_r($node);
}
```

The only problem is that it converts xml tags to lowercase. like `<SItem>` becomes `<sitem>`. So, anyone have idea about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't executed your code but i think you can use PHP logic. If anything doesn't work for you then last solution will be exploding `$simpleXmlNode` to get some array structure and then process it according to your need. By the way can you share what you got after `$simpleXmlNode = simplexml_load_string($node)`?

For others, i can't add comments so posting this as answer.

Comment: for processing I also tried this in while loop:
foreach($simpleXmlNode->SResponse->Body->SResponseDetails->SItem as $item)

And I am getting each node in xmlObject so, I am converting xml object to xml using asXML() function but it convert characters in lowercase.

Comment: can you provide $simpleXmlNode sample value? i will see if find some time to validate it for you?

Comment: can you let me know how I can use asXML() without changing text to lowercase. It is converting xml tags to lowercase.